# Python/Xpath convert query

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying out Scrapy. I've got the following:

```
hxs.select('//span[contains(@itemprop, "price")]').extract()
```

Outputs:

```
[u'<span itemprop="price" class="offer_price">\n<span class="currency">\u20ac</span>\n16<span class="offer_price_fraction">,95</span>\n</span>']
```

How can I retrieve this output:

```
16.95
```

In other words, add price with the fraction price span + replacing the , with .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this single XPath expression:**

```
   translate(
             concat(//span[@itemprop = 'price']/text()[normalize-space()],
                    //span[@itemprop = 'price']/span[@class='offer_price_fraction']
                    ),
             ',',
             '.'
             )
```

**XSLT - based verification:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
  "translate(
          concat(//span[@itemprop = 'price']/text()[normalize-space()],
                  //span[@itemprop = 'price']/span[@class='offer_price_fraction']
                 ),
           ',',
           '.'
            )"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on this XML document:**

```
<span itemprop="price" class="offer_price">
  <span class="currency">\u20ac</span>
16<span class="offer_price_fraction">,95</span>
</span>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the result of this evaluation is copied to the output:**

```
16.95
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I have the XPath Selector setup:

```
>>> hxs.extract()
u'<html><body><span itemprop="price" class="offer_price">\n<span class="currency">\u20ac</span>\n16<span class="offer_price_fraction">,95</span>\n</span></body></html>'
```

and here is how you can achieve the desired result:

```
>>> price = 'descendant::span[@itemprop="price"]'
>>> whole = 'text()'
>>> fract = 'descendant::span[@class="offer_price_fraction"]/text()'
>>> s = hxs.select(price).select('%s | %s' % (whole, fract)).extract()
>>> s
[u'\n', u'\n16', u',95', u'\n']
>>> ''.join(s).strip().replace(',', '.')
u'16.95'
```

Comment: nice, thanks! forgot about the descendant thing, stupid me.. thanks though!